# How can I get a clone of my website taken down?

Tags: seo

There's a clone of my website that I need taken down. They clearly used a script to copy my site inside and out all the way down to the HTML. It's literally hundreds of thousands of URLs that are copied down to the brim. It seems to continuously crawl my site too because their site updates with my updates within hours.

There's no contact info for the owner on the site or in the WHOIS. I contacted the CloudFlare abuse department (they use them), tried the abuse department for their hosting company (but it's a sketchy off shore hosting company), and submitted to Google to have their website de-indexed [here](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard):

So far, nothing's really gotten done. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: so you want to delete everything for this cloned site?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78404/someone-has-cloned-my-wordpress-blog-how-do-i-prevent-it-from-hurting-seo/78411

Comment: May you catch the user-agent of their spider and block it via .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little trick you can try, if that site is using fetching your whole coding, you can try JavaScript redirect [Check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230848/javascript-redirect-back-to-parent-page)

Comment: Only caveat with that idea is that people with javascript turned off in their browser will not be able to use the site if that idea is implemented.

Comment: @Mike: The redirect would only occur on the cloned site, to redirect the user back to the real site by checking the hostname. If JS is disabled then the user is simply not redirected - they just see the cloned site. (At least I think that is the intention?) Although I'm not sure why the link to the SO question - that would only seem to be an example of a JS redirect, there would need to be some additional (concealed) logic.

Answer (score 1):

> So far, nothing's really gotten done. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

If you have not done so, set canonical links containing your domain name in the URLs. It will help Google establish you are the authoritative site.

If you have reported it to Google, it can take some time for algorithms to remove everything from the index. Scrapped content bears no value for rankings.

You could also report this abuse here too: https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en